# Get value at index in table

Tags: lua, lua-table

Is it possible for me to cycle this table asynchronously without really checking state? I would like to be able to do something `colors[count % 6]` or similar where I don't need to check explicitly which state (count) I'm at.

```
colors = {
        red = {max.R,0,0},
        green = {0,max.G,0},
        blue = {0,0,max.B},
        purple = {max.R,0,max.B},
        pink = {max.R,0.1*max.G,0.8*max.B},
        yellow = {max.R*0.95,max.G*0.64,0.5*max.B}
        }
```

I have a timer callback where I want to go through the table one color at a time , but to do so currently I have to do it like `if count == 0 then setColor(colors.red) ...`

Comment: i have a timer callback where i want to go through the table one color at a time , but to do so currently I'm having to do it like `if count == 0 then setColor(colors.red) ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use another index table:

```
local index = {"red", "green", "blue", "purple", "pink", "yellow"}
```

Then you can use `colors[index[count % 6 + 1]]`. The downside is, if the keys of `colors` are modified, `index` needs to be updated manually.

Comment: You can populate the `index` table based on `colors` table: `for color in pairs(colors) do table.insert(index, color) end`.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko If the order of the keys doesn't matter, sure. However, if the order matters, then using `pairs` is not a good idea.

Comment: Agree; just wanted to mention this in case it satisfies OP requirements.